# Excel VBA - Looping a ListObject Column

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Evening SO,

I'm trying to loop through a specific column in a listobject table.  I have executed this and it works perfectly EXCEPT if the column is empty (i.e. table has no rows).  This would be very rare but naturally the master copy of this workbook would be blank and therefore returns an Error 91 for a null object.

How can I make the code execute even if the table is empty without returning an error 91?  I know I can use On Error Resume Next, but that's like taking pain killers, it doesn't address the problem.

```
For Each cell In Worksheets(3).ListObjects("tblTableName").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Cells
  'Do some stuff here
Next
```

The above code executes fine if the table contains data but throws an Error 91 if the table is blank as it will always be in the master copy.

Comment: Why not checking for the count? If there is nothing, then just don't do anything...

Comment: I could certainly use this approach, however I thought that surely there is a way you can check for a Null value as opposed to counting what could end up being thousands of rows.

Comment: Sure, you also could use `If Not TheRangeToCheck is Nothing Then` to ensure the Range is not null...

Comment: So Nothing is the VBA term for a null value?

Comment: Upon further investigation it would appear that DataBodyRange cannot be referenced if there are no rows in the table.  You cannot even reference it to check for a null value, it doesn't even have a Null value, it simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Anyone know if there is a way to check if there is a DataBodyRange without directly referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
Sub test()
 Dim L As ListObject

 Set L = Range("a1").ListObject

 Dim q As Range
 Set q = L.DataBodyRange

 If Not q Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "There's something!"
 Else
    MsgBox "There's nothing!"
 End If

End Sub
```

Could also use:

```
 Dim m As Boolean

 m = L.DataBodyRange Is Nothing
```